# No such element exception in Selenium code using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

While i tried automating a website using selenium and Java i got no such element exception even though i got correct xpath while inspecting the field. After giving a city by sendkeys i tried to select 1st option from dropdown by select method and actions keyword but both didnt work and throwed exception. I will attach the code and image of inspected website.Kindly help with the issue

```
@Test
  public void abhibusHotel() throws Exception {
      driver.get("https://www.abhibus.com/");
      HomePage ohome=new HomePage(driver);
      ohome.hotelPage();
      HotelBooking obook=new HotelBooking(driver);
      obook.bookingDetails();
      Thread.sleep(2000);

public void bookingDetails()
    {
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(city)).sendKeys("Bengaluru");
            //Select se=new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Beng'])[1]/parent::div"))));
            //Select se=new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Beng'][1]"))));

            //se.selectByIndex(1);
            WebElement tooltip= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Beng']/parent::div")));
            oaction.moveToElement(tooltip).click().build().perform();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it inside `iframe` or `frame`?

Comment: no its not inside frame or iframe

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is saying that there are 9 matching elements. Selenium takes the first one. That first one is not necessarily visible. You need to narrow your xpath query so that it returns the only one that represents what is currently visible.

Comment: i have tried with indexing 1st one but same issue like //span[text()='Beng'])[1]/parent::div

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I see two ways of doing it by using the xpath selector

```
//here we'll search for the city
driver.findElement(By.id("ex1_value")).sendKeys("Bengaluru");

//first option - this will give more than one element for the desired text    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ex1_dropdown']/*/div[@ng-if='imageField']/img[contains(@ng-src, " +
                    "'city.png')]/following::div[contains(@ng-bind-html," +
                    " 'result.title')]/span[normalize-space(.='Bengaluru')]")).click();
  
//second option and the tricky one - in your web application the results are unique for the city - and the developers are using an image in the displayed list, you can check by that icon if you need a city, hotel, etc
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ex1_dropdown']/*/div[@ng-if='imageField']/img[contains(@ng-src, " +
                        "'city.png')]")).click();
```

both options are working - but be aware that after the city is selected the website jumps automatically to the next field (the date inputs).